# Find directories that had changes between commits

Tags: git, jenkins, subdirectory, git-diff

I am setting up a jenkins job which iterates over the directories in a project, and performs similar actions inside each of them.

While, for now, since I have a small number of directories, going over all of them is not a big deal. But I'd like to only iterate over the directories which had changes made inside them between the `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` and `GIT_COMMIT`.

What my current job does:

```bash
for dir in */
do
  cd $dir
  # test a script exists
  # execute the script
  # upload the result.zip to an S3 bucket
  cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) with the `--name-only` option. This will list the files changed:

```
$ git diff --name-only GIT_COMMIT..GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT

app/controllers/some_controller.rb
app/models/some_model.rb
app/views/some/show.html.erb
app/views/some/index.html.erb
```

Then, you could pipe this to sed to remove the file names. Then sort & uniq to get a unique list of directories you are interested in:

```
sed 's,/*[^/]\+/*$,,' | sort | uniq 

app/controllers
app/models
app/views/some
```

Comment: I did this, with a slight change, using `cut` as that'd perform better. `git diff --name-only ${GIT_COMMIT}..${GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT} | cut '/' -f 1 | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own alias for such activities. It comes in quite handy!

Add these in your .gitconfig:

```
  38   # Difference between HEAD and HEAD^
  39   dbh = "!git ls --numstat -1"
  40   # Difference between two commits
  41   dbc  = "!f() { git diff --name-status $1 $2; }; f"
```

And then you can use them as:

```
 git dbc ab68a12 fc83334 # for diff between two commits.
```

or

```
git dbh # for diff between previous and current HEAD.
```

Comment: Ls is another alias i have to show the log in pretty format. You can simply replace ls with log --decorate --date=relative